# What are the constants referred to in SICP's definition of order of growth?

Tags: big-o, sicp

In section 1.2.3, *Structure and Interpretation of Programs* gives this formal definition for order of growth:

> We say that R(n) has order of growth Θ(f(n)), written R(n) = Θ(f(n))
>   (pronounced “theta of f(n)”), if there are positive constants k<sub>1</sub> and
>   k<sub>2</sub> independent of n such that k<sub>1</sub>f(n) ≤ R(n) ≤ k<sub>2</sub>f(n) for any sufficiently large value of n. (In other words, for large n, the value R(n) is sandwiched between k<sub>1</sub>f(n) and k<sub>2</sub>f(n).)

What is the significance of the constants k<sub>1</sub> and k<sub>2</sub>? I'm having trouble mapping this formal definition to real world examples, because the constants aren't mentioned again.

Maybe k<sub>1</sub>f(n) ≤ R(n) means that there is some observable growth? And maybe R(n) ≤ k<sub>2</sub>f(n) means that f(n) is the upper limit of the growth? But if R(n) = Θ(f(n)) and k<sub>1</sub> is a positive constant, when would k<sub>1</sub>f(n) ever be less than R(n)? It seems like the condition holds only when k<sub>1</sub> is 1.

Answer (score 0):

R and f are completely different functions that have nothing in common except how they grow relative to n, so there is no reason why f(n) should equal R(n). R is "the amount of resources the process requires for a problem of size n".  f is an unrelated mathematical function.

What makes the definition of Θ particularly confusing is that it doesn't refer to the resource is R is measuring nor the process that is using the resource.

Examples of R(n) could be:

- Number of registers used in summing n numbers.
- Disk used to transcode n GB of video
- Time taken to launch n drones.

But the definition of Θ doesn't mention resources (registers, disk, time), nor processes (summing, transcoding or launching).

If our 'process' is a software procedure called p, then we have three quite different 'functions':

```
p(n) - a procedural function that programmers work with.
R(n) - a measuring function like ones used by engineers.
f(n) – a 'pure' mathematical function.
```

If we use the factorial procedure as an example, which has Θ(n) growth with respect to time, we would have:

```
p(n) = (define (factorial n) (if (= n 1) 1 (* n (factorial (- n 1)))))
R(n) = The time in seconds for (factorial n) to complete.
f(n) = n
```

R(n) = f(n) implies (factorial 17) takes exactly 17 seconds to run, which is unlikely.

The definition of Θ(n) is saying k₁ and k₂ exist so that once n is big enough:

```
k₁ * n <= "Time taken for (factorial n) to run in seconds" <= k₂ * n
```

On a modern computer k₁ would need to be very small for k₁ * n to be less than the actual running time.

For the tree-recursive Fibonacci procedure growth is Θ(1.618ⁿ) so we have:

```
p(n) = (define (fib n) (cond ((= n 0) 0) ((= n 1) 1)  (else ... )))
R(n) = The time in seconds for (fib n) to complete.
f(n) = 1.618ⁿ
```

and the definition is saying k₁ and k₂ exist so that:

```
k₁ * 1.618ⁿ <= "Time taken for (fib n) to run" <= k₂ * 1.618ⁿ)
```

(I've used "1.618" for the golden ration instead of "φ")

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The condition seems trivially obvious. 0.01 * R(n) will _always_ be <= R(n). So too, R(n) is always <= 100 * R(n).  For any factor of n, the condition seems obviously true in the same way. So it seems meaningless. Do you know of a way to make the condition false?

Comment: @maxhallinan I've rewritten my answer, but the original answer was comparing R(n) with R(2n).  If the order of growth is predictable and we know the _actual_ value of R(n) we can calculate the bounds for R(2n).  But We have no idea what the actual value of R(2n) is.  We don't know what resource is being measured by R nor what process is consuming that resource.  The only thing we know about R(2n) or R(1000n) are the ranges they will be in.  We can estimate R(2n) = 4*R(n) but that is just an estimate.